# Phonetic Alphabet Trainer

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map, quiz

This is a little program I put together to help people learn the phonetic alphabet. Feel free to query the code.

```
import random

phonetic = {    'a' : 'alpha',    'b' : 'bravo',    'c' : 'charlie',    'd' : 'delta',    'e' : 'echo',    'f' : 'foxtrot',    'g' : 'golf',    'h' : 'hotel',    'i' : 'india',    'j' : 'juilett',    'k' : 'kilo',    'l' : 'lima',    'm' : 'mike',    'n' : 'november',    'o' : 'oscar',    'p' : 'papa',    'q' : 'quebec',    'r' : 'romeo',    's' : 'sierra',    't' : 'tango',    'u' : 'uniform',    'v' : 'victor',    'w' : 'whiskey',    'x' : 'x-ray',    'y' : 'yankee',    'z' : 'zulu'    }

print('Welcome to the IkeaFish Phonetic Trainer. \n Answer no or n to stop the program.')

again = 'yes'
while again != 'no' or 'n':

    #Picks either 0 or 1. If equal to 1 tests the letters, If equal to 0, tests the words.
    if random.randint(0,1) == 1:

        question = random.choice(list(phonetic.keys()))        
        answer = input('What does this letter {} stand for: '.format(question))

        if answer == phonetic[question]:
            print('Correct')            
        else:
            print('Wrong answer', question, 'stands for', phonetic[question])

    else:
        letter = random.choice(list(phonetic.keys()))
        #Grabbing a random key
        question = phonetic[letter]                  
        answer = input('What does this word {} stand for: '.format(question))

        if answer == letter:
            print('Correct')            
        else:
            print('Wrong answer', question, 'stands for', phonetic[letter])
```

Comment: Note that the [official word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) for "A" is "Alfa", with "Alpha" being an acceptable variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line

```
while again != 'no' or 'n'
```

is incorrect: `again != 'no' or 'n'` is evaluated to `(again != 'no') or 'n'` which is `True` as `'n'` evaluates to `True` in any case.
You have to use `again != 'no' and again != 'n'` here
    or `again not in ['no', 'n']`.

Anyway, I replaced it with `while True` and added a `break` statement. This allows to exit from the loop exactly when we need it. (Otherwise we get unnecessary message that our answer is not correct.) Also your `again` variable never changed, so your loop in any case is infinite.

I also did several improvements that you can see in the code, and updated the spelling to match the NATO phonetic spellings.

```
import random

phonetic = {'a': 'alfa', 'b': 'bravo', 'c': 'charlie', 'd' : 'delta',
            'e': 'echo', 'f': 'foxtrot', 'g': 'golf', 'h': 'hotel', 
            'i': 'india', 'j': 'juliett', 'k': 'kilo',
            'l': 'lima', 'm': 'mike', 'n': 'november', 'o': 'oscar',    
            'p': 'papa', 'q': 'quebec', 'r': 'romeo', 
            's': 'sierra', 't': 'tango', 'u': 'uniform', 'v': 'victor',
            'w' : 'whiskey', 'x': 'x-ray', 'y': 'yankee', 'z': 'zulu'}
# made this a bit more pep8-compliant

print("Welcome to the IkeaFish Phonetic Trainer.\nAnswer 'no' or 'stop' to stop the program.")
# n can be valid answer, so it is not good to use it a stop-word

while True:    

    letter, word = random.choice(list(phonetic.items())) 
    # we can pick both elements at once

    if random.choice([True, False]):
        answer = input('What does this letter {} stand for: '.format(letter))
        correct = word            
    else:
        answer = input('What does this word {} stand for: '.format(word))
        correct = letter

    answer = answer.lower()
    # make answers case-insensetive

    if answer in ['no', 'stop']:
        break

    if answer == correct:
        print('Correct')            
    else:
        print('Wrong answer', letter, 'stands for', word)
```

Comment: I would change two `if` statements. Change `if answer in ['no', 'stop']:` to `if answer.lower() in ['no', 'stop']:` and change `if answer == correct:` to `if answer.lower() == correct:` This so the user can type upper or lower case but the `if` statements will still work.

Comment: Good point, I thought about it. Added line `answer = answer.lower()` to address both issues.